Are/what makes German parliamentary elections harder to organize than French ones?
On the eve of the European parliamentary election on June 09, 2024, French president Macron called a snap election for the National Assembly. It was held three/four weeks later. (First round on June 30, second round July 7.)
On November 06, 2024, German Chancellor Olaf Scholz fired his finance minister, effectively ending the coalition with the latter's party and thus losing the support of a majority in parliament, but announced he would not resign and only put forward a motion of confidence, required for dissolving parliament and scheduling a new election, in January, leading to a new election in March, because having an election earlier would be impractical. Amid criticism of that approach, the Federal Returning Officer (Bundeswahlleiterin) also warned of "uncalculable risks" should elections be held as "early" as late January or early February (source in German).
I realize Germany's mixed direct/proportional representation system takes more effort in putting together candidate lists for the proportional part, as does collecting signatures for ballot access for smaller/new parties, but most of the issues cited are organizational (ballot printing,  finding election officials...). What specific issues allow France to organize elections within three weeks but might prevent Germany from doing so with 9+ weeks advance notice?

See for example here https://www.bundeswahlleiterin.de/bundestagswahlen/2025/termine.html which goes like 97 days before an election. No clue if they could shorten it if needed. Maybe Scholz simply don't want to do the same as Macron. Impracticality might not be the only reason.

See also the last time this happened in 2005 https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertrauensfrage#2005:_Gerhard_Schr%C3%B6der which took roughly three weeks to dissolve the Parliament after the relevant vote and less than three month later another general election.

Are you asking about the 60 days or the warning for an extended period by the Wahlleiterin? For the latter, the prose of the linked article makes it clear the issue is the Christmas/holiday season, which can easily remove 2-4 weeks of useable time. »Soweit Termine und Fristen in die Weihnachtszeit oder in den Zeitraum zwischen den Jahren fallen würden, wäre der nur sehr knappe Zeitraum von 60 Tagen maßgeblich verkürzt«

"Federal Returning Officer" What does this mean? The term "returning officer" is not one with a well understood meaning in English. Even in this rather literal translation of the German word it is unclear. Is this a chief elections administration officer, or is it something different?

@ohwilleke, yes they are the administrative officers. The Federal election ordonance defines in §1-3 three levels: a federal officer, state officers, and "Kreiswahlleiter", responsible for one constituency.

@ccprog Do they only administer elections or do they have broader responsibilities? Is it a seasonal position?

The federal and state officers are permanent positons, the constituency officers are only appointed temporarily. The state officers are normally also responsible for state and communal elections. That does not say their job is full-time. Traditionally, the Federal and State returning officers also head the respecitve statistics agency.

@ohwilleke Apparently "returning officer" is a thing worldwide. And here I thought it was a case of us Germans being creative with words.

This question essentially asks: why can France organize an election in 3 weeks, but in Germany there is some misgivings about a longer deadline. That is apples v. oranges. Who says Germany can't do it, and do we know nobody had to work overtime in France? Maybe Ms Brand is just precautionally covering her back in case things go wrong? And note she has already received a lot of pushback for her letter.

One would have thought that if the constitution sets 60 days, then you set things up so it actually can be organized in 60 days. Or otherwise the constitution is changed to leave enough time.

I have to remind you that organising elections in 30 days was also criticised in France, especially as they were occurring right before summer vacations. I see no difference with the french snap elections in June

What you are really asking about is comparing the processes applied in Germany and France. I suspect the number of people that really have an overview of the adminstrative details in both is relatively small.
I can only answer from the viewpoint of knowing the processes in Germany, and look at French laws and ordonances and try to spot obvious differences that may account for the slower preparations in Germany. I really beg those readers who are knowledgable about the situation in France to correct my erroneous assumptions.
I'll leave out of my answer the complexity of compiling party lists, as you have pointed at them yourself, and the special circumstances of working around the christmas season.

Election officials
Each polling station in Germany is headed by a committee of at least six persons: a chairman and deputy chairman, a secretary and deputy secretary, and at least two auxilliaries.
All of them have to be found among the electorate by the local returning officer. The main method is calling for volunteers among the public and contacting everyone who has done the job in the past. As an incentive, a small renumeration for the work (federal: 40 Euro) is offered, people working for the state can instead take a half day off. – As a result, working as an election official is relatively popular among teachers.
Theoretically, it would be possible for the returning officer to pick helpers from the electorate at random and enroll them forcibly. But this is considered the very last resort, as no-one gains if they do not show up, or are not motivated to do the job properly.
All in all, gathering the required number of officials, which amount to roundabout 0.5% of the electorate, is a tenacious process.
Also, since none of the officials are professional adminstrators, training them for their function is crucial. Dates have to be found for these training sessions, with reasonable advance notices. I don't have an overview for other states, but I know in Berlin all chairmen, secretaries and their deputies have to take part. For each electoral constituency (200.000 voters on average), around 20 sessions with 50+ attendants are typically scheduled, spread out over two weeks.
Looking at the ordonance governing the work of election officials in France, the process is noticably leaner. Each polling station is headed by at least four persons, "a chairman, at least two assessors and a secretary chosen by them from among the electors of the municipality."
The mayor of the commune, his adjuncts and the members of the city council are required to fill the chairmen roles. Only if their number is depleted, other members of the electorate will be choosen. Each candidate has the right to name one assessor and one substitute for each polling station, choosen from the electorate of the whole département, and if the required number is not met, the mayor of the commune can name a member of the city council to fill in.
France is more rural than Germany, and a lot of communes are much smaller. Accordingly, the number of mayors and city councils is much higher. That helps, but especially in larger cities it is not enough. The chairmen and secretaries get a renummeration for their work (200+ Euro). But parties struggle to name assessors, who are expected to work for free. Consequently, some cities have started to offer money to motivate citizens to become assessors.
Conclusion: France seems to have found a mode where aquiring election officials is not without difficulties, but at least partial solutions are offered by law. In Germany by contrast, the returning officers are left alone with that headache. Each and every election campaign is accompanied by public appearances of the returning officers begging for helpers, and stating that a mere three weeks before election day, they are still seeking thousands of volunteers.
Returning officers
In Germany, the local organisation of elections is based on the 298 electoral constituencies. Each district has one committee to oversee proceedings, and one returning officer (with a temporary office of maybe 10 employees). He may be able to also activate additional capacities for organisation from the communes the constituency spans, but basically everything that needs to be done locally is his responsibility.
In France, the local organisation is based on the communes, which act in their own right. There are 35,000 collectivités, each with a mayor (maire), (at least some) staff, and a council (conseil municipal). They all can be activated for elections, and have the needed authority to organise things.
Conclusion: The French way of spreading out the work to a large number of small units might for elections well be more efficient than the German federalism, which on a sub-state level is often characterized by each administrative level guarding his jurisdiction jealously.
Vote invitation
In Germany, each elector is sent a card or letter inviting him/her to take part in an election. These notices are prepared from the voters registers, and contain not only the address of the polling station the voter should present themselves at, but also a number for finding their entry in the register.
Preparing these invitations requires the assignment of the voters to precincts and their respective polling station, and the location of the stations to be known. While in general not much changes from election to election, both requirements are formally prepared for each election separately.
In France, as far as I can make out, no invitation to an individual election is sent. Instead, voters are issued a polling card (Carte d'électeur) valid for multiple elections. This card assigns them a precinct, notes the location of the polling station and certifies their inscription in the voters register.
The reason why the assignment can be done this way is because the distribution of the voters to precincts are prepared independently of election dates. The mayor of each commune publishes a list of precincts and their respective polling stations on a yearly basis.
Conclusion: The French method of treating precinct assignment and the waiving of sending individual invitations removes a major time limit.
Ballots
In Germany, there is one ballot containing the names of all candidates, and voting consists of ticking a box. The ballots are printed by the returning officer, who obviously is dependent on the parties and candidates providing the needed names in a timely fashion.
In France, the procedure was described by user Relaxed, thanks for that. Each candidate or party has to take care of printing his/her own ballot (they can get the costs reimbursed by the state but they have to make sure they are printed in time to be distributed by mail and to all polling stations). Voting consists of choosing one of these standardized papers and putting it in a small envelope. Ballots and optionally an acompaigning leaflet can be sent as a package prepared by the city to the voters, if they are available in time. If the ballots are not provided early enough, voters can pick them at the polling station. It's not uncommon for the ballots from small / fringe candidates to be missing on election day. But even then they are not excluded from the election. As long as they met the deadline to register, if someone somehow comes up with a valid ballot, it should be tallied and reported.
Conclusion: I am hard pressed to decide whether it is faster to collect information and print them up centrally, or to print decentralized, and then collect papers. What will be in favor of the French method is the very pragmatic handling of deadlines: either you come up with the ballot until election day, or no one can vote for you.
Postal voting
In Germany, postal voting (or early voting by requesting, receiving and filling out the postal voting forms and ballots at city hall in one go) is a popular form of voting, used by up to a third of the electorate. In case of a snap election, the timeline for postal voting may be abridged, but it still has to be made available.
France has no postal voting, except for expatriates. Everyone has to show up at the polling station on election day, or authorize a mandatee to vote in his/her place.

Apparently, lack of election workers and supervisors did cause issues in France. These issues were deemed acceptable given the extraordinary circumstances of the early election: https://www.lefigaro.fr/nice/legislatives-en-manque-d-assesseurs-dans-ses-bureaux-de-vote-la-mairie-de-nice-veut-attirer-les-candidats-avec-une-remuneration-20240625

@xyldke Thank you for the hint. I have modified the answer accordingly.

@xyldke "These issues were deemed acceptable given the extraordinary circumstances of the early election..." The extraordinary circumstances could have been seen as not so urgent (France wasn't really in any emergency situation (earth quake, ...)) so one also could have deemed small delays (say a few weeks more) acceptable for not having these issues and still having a relatively early election.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The article actually argues just the opposite: the timeline for snap elections is a constitutional stipulation, paying the assessors or using civil servants are matters of an ordonance that no-one would argue endangered the validity of the election, and so the volunteer rules were broken/bent in favor of the timeline.

@ccprog So one of the two countries simply optimizes for speed, the other for thorough preparation, kind of.

In France, it is customary for voters to receive a voting package at home with ballots for all the candidates and a one-page campaign leaflet from each of the candidates / parties. It does take time to print, gather, and post those and there were problems with that for the June-July snap election but, as long as you are registered, you can still show up to your polling station with only your ID and vote even if you didn't receive anything.

In fact, the parties / candidates have to take care of printing the ballots (they can get the costs reimbursed by the state but they have to make sure they are printed in time to be distributed by mail and to all polling stations) so that it's not uncommon for the ballots from small / fringe candidates to be missing on election day but even that doesn't invalidate the election.

Note that the constitutional timeline is a bit of a red herring: 20 days is the absolute minimum (it's forbidden to organize election faster than that), not something that's mandated by the constitution and there is absolutely nothing that prevents announcing elections in advance and waiting to actually dissolve parliament later in the summer. This was entirely a tactical move by Macron (possibly in the hope that opposition parties would have too little time to regroup or to avoid facing an election after the extent of the budget gaps became fully clear to the public).

@Relaxed do I understand you right: every candidate has its own ballot (piece of paper), and voting means to select one of them and throw them into the box?

@ccprog Yes, exactly, voting in France doesn't involve putting a mark on a ballot but picking a separate piece of paper and putting it in a small envelop (it's forbidden and invalid to put the ballot directly in the box, you need to use a standard colored envelop provided at the polling station). Size, paper quality, etc. are all regulated but ballots can be printed with colored ink. Here is how it looks like

Also a small nuance, the ballots can always be reimbursed but if a party or candidate also wants to include a leaflet (“circulaire”) with additional information, they only get money to pay for that if they get at least 5% of the vote.

Here is a picture of what you might get at home The A4 pages are the circulaires, the smaller pieces of paper are the ballots. Envelop is not included to make it more difficult to coerce a vote (you cannot ask someone to show you that they are putting the “right” ballot in the envelop, they only do that when they are alone in the voting booth).

@Relaxed Suppose you do not bring your own, but pick ballots at the station. How do you get them into the envelope without everyone seeing which paper you picked? Even if using a private booth, wouldn't it be obvious if you take one, glaringly colered paper in with you? Or, if you take them all, which of them is missing afterwards?

@ccprog It is actually mandatory to take at least two. It is also forbidden not to use the voting booth. There is a trash bin in or very near the voting booth where all the discarded ballots end up.

Finally, color is increasingly common but for the presidential election, ballots look like this or this

@Relaxed thanks for all that information, I've added another paragraph to my answer. For the tactical part, that is more a matter for haxor's answer.

No problem, if you prefer, feel free to remove the acknowledgment to make your answer more readable ;)

Just one last point I forgot to mention: Even if a candidate didn't provide any ballots, they are still not excluded from the election. As long as they met the deadline to register as a candidate, if someone somehow comes up with a valid ballot, it should be tallied and reported. For some elections, the interior ministry even provides PDF files of the ballots.

Christmas
Regular elections happen 46 to 48 months after the beginning of the previous election period. The election officials set the date somewhere within those two months, customarily on a Sunday. There is some political jockeying between states with staggered school breaks to get the date which is most convenient for them.
An election following the dissolution of the parliament has much shorter timelines than a regular election. They happen within 60 days of the dissolution of parliament. Since it is unlikely that the dissolution is on a Sunday, there would be eight weeks or less to work with.
Two of the next eight weeks contain Christmas and the New Year, which both fall right in the middle of the week. As ccprog pointed out, staff has to be found and trained. Polling stations have to be selected and rented (if not already public buildings). Ballots have to be printed and distributed. Voters receive notifications by mail, which state the exact location of their polling station, so that must be known in time for the letters to be printed.
One could argue that elections are more important than Christmas, and that the holidays are cancelled for civil servants. But that would be a mess.

"a mess" is an understatement here. That would probably imply declaring a state of emergency or similar, I don't think there would be any support for this.

I would also hazard a guess that the amount of vote by mail would be much higher than usual since people are, well, on holidays. That too requires more preparation than usual.

Apparently, it's actually not that easy to find printers that can do the job of printing all the voting papers.

@gerrit Whereas we have now learned that procuring the actual paper is not the issue after all ;-)

@SebastianKoppehel, timelines would get critical, not the amount of paper. If we were to vote in January, the notifications would have to be mailed in December. But printing can only start once the date is set. All that on short notice is not impossible, but it increases the risk of screwups.

The elephant is somewhat that the questions that need to be considered aren't just: "Can you organize elections fast", but also "Should you organize elections fast" and "Do the respective parties WANT to organize elections fast".
There are some organizational things that just take time, appointing, hiring, training people, printing and distributing material, currently many of the deadlines for elections are outside of the 60 day limit, so the department of the interior needs to craft a new law adjusting those deadlines. That all takes some time, but is also frequently exercised with regular elections. So it's likely not impossible to do those things faster, it's just more of a hurry and there's less space for mistakes and a higher chance of them happening.
The other thing is that even if you streamline the organizational problems, the party politics themselves causes new one's that are harder to streamline. For example before the ballots can be printed the parties need to submit the list of their candidates and the order of them (which includes both direct mandates where 1 party submits one name for regional representation as well as a whole list of people for proportional representation). Smaller parties might also require to get a set number of signatures to be allowed on the ballot.
So parties have to collect names faster, have to ask people for signatures faster, the submitted data has to be checked faster as retracting wrong ballots or dropping candidates would be a disaster for organization or even democracy.
So unless pressingly urgent you might want to give that some time to make things write and don't fuck up somewhere.
On top of that parties also need to organize a campaign, set up a program, start printing campaign related stuff and get that distributed and out there. So of course you can technically shorten that quite significantly the effect of that would be that those established parties who are already well known get to benefit or suffer from that, while the smaller parties probably lack most of that recognition. There again a shorter list of parties due to first pas the post election systems, might be an advantage with regards to speed. You just know your usual suspects already.

Edit:Apparently in France (according to @Relaxed), the voting is not done by making a mark on the ballot, but parties provide their own ballots which are then filled into envelops and which can come with additional information. Which might put a lot more overhead on the respective parties than previously assumed. Though even if no valid is provided you can apparently print your own as long as the candidate registered in time. So the printing process can be made slightly faster that way.
But as that is only one factor in the equation and likely not the most time consuming one. This still means that snap elections would feel rushed for the parties to get all things up and running.

And as o.m. has argued, doing that in the Christmas season is a nightmare, but not just because of the organization and officials being on vacation, but also because of the voters being on vacation and in Christmas mode. So good luck trying to have a conversation with the locals who are gift shopping, or getting your banners seen when competing with all businesses for ad space on likely the most important season of their business year... or get signatures while they are visiting their families... So yeah things can get messy.
Again it might be possible if necessary, but is that really a good idea?
And last but not least do the respective parties actually want that? Like if they really want to cut things short or are pressed by external constraints to make it fast, people can usually find ways to do it. But afai can see there's not really that much of a willingness to do it that fast.
Like yes technically Scholz (chancellor) has fired Lindner (finance minister), but practically Lindner had already been in campaign mode for quite some time ranting against the government WHILE BEING PART OF THAT GOVERNMENT. So while I'm not sure it did his party any good, he technically has a head start with respect to starting campaigning. So does the opposition, who can always complain that the government sucks. While the remaining part of the government coalition has for the last weeks still be in compromise mode to savor the coalition from collapsing.
So doing snap elections also might have the effect of freezing the current mood. So Macron somewhat hoped that it would give his party a greater majority and that it would curb the far right headwind if people wouldn't get too much time under that influence but were pressed to decide now if that is a good idea.
While the remaining part of the government coalition wouldn't really want the current mood fixed in place but would likely get more space to fix their image. So the government liked to push a later date, while the opposition would like to have a snap election at best.
Also rushing an election while leading a failing coalition and risking voting irregularities because of a rushed election wouldn't be a good look either so giving it it's due time and making it more like a professional way out is likely preferable too.
And last but not least Scholz apparently also has some laws in the pipeline that they want to get passed before the parliament resolves and which he hopes to get passed even without a government majority, because the opposition might agree with the urgency of these measures.
That being said the opposition apparently doesn't want that given that in current polls:
https://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/index.htm
They currently have a lead over the government parties and might want to take credit for those projects themselves. Though delaying them just for party politics can also be a double edged sword.
Either way tl;dr it might not just be a question of whether it can be done but also a question of whether it makes sense to do it faster and whether the actors WANT to do it faster. Also previous unscheduled elections also often took some time before actually asking the question.
Also with regard to the 60 days. Despite thing taking time, the parliament is the most important institution in the German democracy and the one electing the government so having that be vacant or defunct for longer than necessary or to have a government be able to make decisions outside of parliament is something that is to be avoided and has very dangerous precedent in German history.

User @Relaxed just posted some comments, one of them follows up on your thoughts about political tactics regarding the French election. Maybe you want to include them in your answer?

@ccprog Thanks for the reminder, was an interesting read and I'll look when I find the time to update my answer.
